# Django filter multiple foreign key relationships

Tags: django, django-templates, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I want to list all of a teacher's students that have commented on each genre of blog posts. Below is my best effort, but I duplicate student names for each genre, so if they comment on multiple scary blog posts, their names are listed multiple times. How can I list each student name once next to each genre on the teacher profile page?

**Models.py**

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student_profile')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('Teacher', blank=True, null=True)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teacher_profile')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, unique=True)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name='comments', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    message = CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    commenter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
def teacher_profile(request):
student_list = Student.objects.filter(teacher__user=request.user)
student_blogpost_list = BlogPost.objects.filter(comments__commenter__student_profile__teacher__user=request.user).distinct()
student_genre_list = Genre.objects.filter(blogpost__in=student_blogpost_list).distinct()
return render(
    request,
    'myapp/teacher_profile.html',
    context= {'student_list':student_list, 'student_blogpost_list':student_blogpost_list, 'student_genre_list':student_genre_list},
)
```

**teacher_profile.html**

```
{% if student_genre_list %}
  <h4>Genres</h4>
  {% for genre in student_genre_list %}
    Genre: {{ genre.name }} - Students: 
    {% for blogpost in genre.blogpost_set.all %}
      {% for comment in blogpost.comments.all %}
        {% if comment.commenter.student_profile in student_list %}
          {{ comment.commenter.student_profile.username }}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  <br>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be done in following way:

```
student_list = Student.objects.filter(teacher__user=request.user)
student_blogpost_list = BlogPost.objects.filter(comments__commenter__student_profile__teacher__user=request.user).distinct()

data = dict()
for blogpost in student_blogpost_list:
    students_usernames = list(blogpost.comment_set.filter(commenter__in=student_list).
                             values_list('commenter__student_profile__username', flat=True))
    if blogpost.genre.name in data:
        data[blogpost.genre.name].append(students_usernames)
    else:
        data[blogpost.genre.name] = students_usernames

for key in data.keys():
    data[key] = set(data[key]) # remove duplicates from list
```

`data` variable will be equal to something like:

```
{'genre_1': {'username_1', 'username_2'}, 'genre_2': {'username_2', 'username_3', 'username_4'}}
```

My point is that there should not be a lot of logic in template. Using this approach you'll just need to iterate over result dictionary.
Nevertheless, I can't guarantee that this code is working, as I didn't set up database with the same scheme.